# Any support for reading/writing hexfloats from/to delimited files?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, scipy

Does the Python standard library or scipy/numpy/pandas, etc., provide any support for reading and writing hexadecimal representations of floating point numbers (aka "hexfloats") to and from delimited files (e.g. TSV or CSV)?

As a test, I made a CSV file where the columns alternated between decimal and hexadecimal floats, and tried reading this file using `pandas.read_csv`.  In the resulting dataframe, the columns containing decimal floats were correctly converted into Python floats, whereas the ones containing hexadecimal floats were left as strings.

---

EDIT: clarification: I don't need help converting hexfloats into floats, and vice-versa.  There's `float.fromhex` and `float.hex` for that.  What I'm looking for is for a file reader that will apply reasonable heuristics to automatically convert hexfloats into floats (just like `pandas.read_csv` knows to convert decimal representations of numbers into numeric Python objects).

Comment: What would be the delimiter in such a file?

Comment: @hpaulj: whatever does not interfere with the data: comma, tab, [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators), etc.

Comment: Is there a `%` format that would work?  e.g. `%???`%12.23`?

Comment: I've never seen such a file format. One either has a binary file, if necessary with a header describing the format, or you need a delimiter, because the length of a number (as a string) is not related to it's value.

Comment: _"Just like csv.reader knows to convert decimal representations of numbers into numeric Python objects"_ - You mean [not converting them](https://ideone.com/WKOps7) then? csvreader does just as good a job at hex floats as it does ints :)

Comment: @Eric: thanks for catching that; I've fixed my question accordingly.  I had though, incorrectly, that pandas' csv-reading functonality came all from `csv`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything in the `%` formatting specs that will create a `hex` for a float (just `%x` for ints).  So accepting your `float.hex`, I can create a function that converts every float in an array into a hex string:

```
def foo(x):
    return x.hex()
vfoo=np.vectorize(foo)   # just for ease of applying foo to an array

In [478]: x=np.arange(12.).reshape(3,4)/3

In [479]: x
Out[479]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ],
       [ 1.33333333,  1.66666667,  2.        ,  2.33333333],
       [ 2.66666667,  3.        ,  3.33333333,  3.66666667]])

In [480]: vfoo(x)
Out[480]: 
array([['0x0.0p+0', '0x1.5555555555555p-2', '0x1.5555555555555p-1',
        '0x1.0000000000000p+0'],
       ['0x1.5555555555555p+0', '0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+0',
        '0x1.0000000000000p+1', '0x1.2aaaaaaaaaaabp+1'],
       ['0x1.5555555555555p+1', '0x1.8000000000000p+1',
        '0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1', '0x1.d555555555555p+1']], 
      dtype='<U20')
```

then I can use the usual `savetxt` to write those strings to a file

```
In [481]: np.savetxt('test.txt',vfoo(x), fmt='%25s',delimiter=',')
```

Which looks like:

```
In [482]: cat test.txt
                 0x0.0p+0,     0x1.5555555555555p-2,     0x1.5555555555555p-1,     0x1.0000000000000p+0
     0x1.5555555555555p+0,     0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+0,     0x1.0000000000000p+1,     0x1.2aaaaaaaaaaabp+1
     0x1.5555555555555p+1,     0x1.8000000000000p+1,     0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1,     0x1.d555555555555p+1
```

and `loadtxt` can handle this

```
In [486]: np.loadtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')
Out[486]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ],
       [ 1.33333333,  1.66666667,  2.        ,  2.33333333],
       [ 2.66666667,  3.        ,  3.33333333,  3.66666667]])
```

`loadtxt` uses this piece of code when it sees `0x` columns

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    656         x.lower()
    657         if b'0x' in x:
--> 658             return float.fromhex(asstr(x))
```

You might get other ideas by studying the `npyio.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from struct import unpack
hex_string="abcd33ef"
my_bytes = unhexlify(hex_string)
my_float = unpack("f",my_bytes)
```

I guess ... maybe?